# Image upload in editor - Best approach?

Tags: javascript, tinymce, image-uploading

I am using tinymce editor in my project. For image upload, i am converting image to base64 and displaying the same in the editor.
That is, i am not uploading any data to server. The code is as follows.

```
<Editor
                              initialValue={selectedDocument.html_content}
                              init={{
                                plugins: 'link image code, lists',
                                toolbar: 'undo redo | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright | code | numlist bullist',
                                height: 600,
                                forced_root_block : "",
                                force_br_newlines : true,
                                force_p_newlines : false,
                                images_upload_handler: function (blobInfo, success, failure) {
                                  // no upload, just return the blobInfo.blob() as base64 data
                                  success("data:" + blobInfo.blob().type + ";base64," + blobInfo.base64());
                                },
                                setup: function(editor) {
                                  me.tinyMce = editor;
                                }
                              }}
                              onChange={this.handleEditorChange}
                            />
```

I am just wondering if this is the right approach. Does this approach has any drawback?

or Should i upload the image to server and use the image url instead?

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should Upload images separately to the server and replace the base64 images string with the URLs returned from the server.

#### why?

1. base64 images are huge. if you have couple of them it will kill the performance of your editor and your app. you will experience lags when image is added to the editor.
2. since base64 images are just plain strings. when you upload them your post body becomes enormous. which may cause API failure if you haven't configured server properly.
3. saving RichText HTML alone is huge for your database. if you add base64 image strings to it. your database will also suffer handling such data.